# mod_rewrite append GET-Parameter to current URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've a webpages in form of

```
domain.tld/product/a
domain.tld/product/b
```

This pages have links in form of `./service?pageId=12345`

Is it possible with `mod_rewrite` to define a rule to append the parameter `pageId` to the current product-url in form of `domain.tld/product/b?pageId=12345`

I tried a lot of combinations of

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageId=(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) /pageId=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Without success.

Is this possible with `mod_rewrite`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i think i found a solution with %{HTTP_REFERER}

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageId=(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) %{HTTP_REFERER}?pageId=%1 [R=301,L]
```

It works for me...